# Get the current drawable in the Imageview of appWidget

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to get the current drawable of the ImageView of the widget of my app. But there is no `getDrawable()` in appWidgetProvider. How to get the current drawable of the Imageview?

Ex. if I have current drawable `A` in the imageview, I want to change it to `B`. But first I want to check if it is `A` or `B` and then change accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get the current drawable of the Imageview?

That is not possible, sorry.

However, since you are the one who is defining what drawable is used by the `RemoteViews`, you can track this yourself, holding onto an appropriate identifier in a database, `SharedPreferences`, or other sort of file.